# How to classify a very large amount of text in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, nlp

## I have to classify very large amounts of text in over 10,000 categories. I will need expert advice because I am still a student.

My data is descriptions and titles of commercial products sorted into categories. For exemple, a keyboard with title "large and good keyboard" is in category office > computer > keyboard.

For now, i use "from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer" for represent my text data. But the matrix is too big in memory.
Do you have any tips for representing a large amount of data?

I was thinking of using word-2-vec to represent the data followed by a neural network for classification.

### But I need your advice to get on the right path !!

### Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your issue here? Have you tried fitting classifiers to your data and are you saying it's "too big" because it took too much time?

Comment: Also, it doesn't make much sense to have tfidf vectorization and then applying word2vec... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My data is description and title of commercial product. And my target is the category of product. For example, a keyboard has the description "large keyboard" and it is classified in the category office> computer> keyboard. For the moment i use "from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer" on my data, but the matrix is very large in memory. Is there another solution for represent text data ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I see two options for you if you want to reduce the size of the Tfidf vectorization.

Suppose you have the following data:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

X = ["When I wake up in the morning I always eat apples",
"What do you eat in the morning",
"Usually I only drink coffee",
"How awful, I really cannot stand coffee"]
```

When applying Tfidf transformation, you will get a matrix of shape (4,21):

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectorized_X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
vectorized_X.shape
>>> (4,21)
```

Now let us assume having 21 columns is too much, and that we wanted to reduce it.

## **Option 1**

You can use dimensionality reduction. The most natural once you have performed Tfidf is to use the truncated SVD. This performs linear dimensionality reduction on your tfidf vectorization. The nice thing about it is that you can specify the number of new components you wish to keep:

```
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
reduced_X = svd.fit_transform(vectorized_X)
reduced_X.shape
>>> (4,2)
```

## **Option 2**

Tfidf allows you to specify how many words you want to keep in your vectorization. It then returns a vectorization performed only on the top words in terms of term frequency.

```
vectorizer_reduction = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 5)
vectorized_reduced_X = vectorizer_reduction.fit_transform(X)
vectorized_reduced_X.shape
>>> (4,5)
```

If I had the choice between the two, I would go for **Option 1** because it first takes all information into account and then summarizes it, whereas **Option 2** just discards information right from the start. But I would also expect **Option 1** to take longer... so maybe the optimal solution could be a blend of the two (first apply a restrictive Tfidf, and then SVD)?

Comment: A mix between the two methods seems to me a good choice. I will test to get the best ratio between speed and good prediction rate. Thank you for your clear and precise answer !

Comment: I also thought of another solution, it is to use word-2-vec. With the library " gensim"  (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html), It seems easy. According to the documentation, text vectorization can be done without loading the whole into memory. What do you think of this option?

Comment: @ToniGarcia If you want to be using word2vec, the next question is: what are you going to with it? This will convert each of your sentences into matrices, which is best handled with Neural Networks. If this is the path you want to go down, it's fine. This is a radically different option than converting text to tfidf.

Comment: My real problem is to train a classifier with data that is not storable in memory. I tried to transform the sentences into a matrix by using word-2-vec to then train a classifier.But it takes too much time. So I trained an SGD using partial_fit on sklearn. I will write an answer about this with my code.

Comment: I have write a answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to train a classifier without having to store all the data in memory.

Imagine you have 2 dataset for train 1 classifier.

```
#Data 1
X1_text = ["When I wake up in the morning I always eat apples",
     "What do you eat in the morning"]
y1 = [1,1] #target 1
#Data 2
X2_text = ["Usually I only drink coffee",
     "How awful, I really cannot stand coffee"]
y2 = [2,2] #target 2
```

We using Hashing for vectorize data

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(decode_error='ignore', n_features=2 ** 18)
X1 = vectorizer.transform(X1_text)
X2 = vectorizer.transform(X2_text)
```

We will use partial_fit to train an SGDClassifier in 2 steps. 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html

```
from sklearn.linear_model.stochastic_gradient import SGDClassifier
clf = SGDClassifier()
```

First step, using partial_fit for X1 / y1 . The parameter classes must contain all possible classes to predict. Here it's 1 and 2 . 
note: if you have , for exemple, variable classes with all target you can use classes = np.unique(classes). See documentation.

```
clf.partial_fit(X1, y1, classes = [1,2])
```

Second step, re-train classifieur with other data. Don't use attribut classes.

```
clf.partial_fit(X2, y2)
```